# jquery selectbox css - trying to change the font color doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the text color in the dropdown boxes in a jquery selectbox plugin.

You would have thought changing the color in:
.sbOptions a:link, .sbOptions a:visited {} and/or 
.sbOptions a:hover, .sbOptions a:focus, .sbOptions a.sbFocus {}

would have done the trick but surprisingly it doesn't and I can't figure out why. I don't know if it's perhaps something to do with the javascript

here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/38/

Comment: it seems link color changing when clicking on top dropdown link, you need to check inside the plugin css, maybe some rule is blocking those events (:hover,:focus,:link,:visited), then don't understand what you need sincerily, do you need those events to change color on dropdown links?

Comment: if you just need to change all links colors use **!important** when somenthing is not changing it's a good fix, it will give to your css rules first priority!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/39/

You can use `$(".sbSelector").css('color','Red');` to change color.

And you can also try `$(".sbSelector").css('backgroundColor','#ee55ee');`

http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/44/

Comment: @Zaphod Beeblebrox: If I am getting you right this could be a solution. Is it Okay to you?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me
I tried

```
.sbOptions a:link, .sbOptions a:visited{
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sbOptions a:hover,
.sbOptions a:focus,
.sbOptions a.sbFocus{
    color: #ddd;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQKax/43/)**

Comment: this works too. Looks like I buggered up somehow, thought I'd tried everything

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox This should be the accepted answer, jam's suggestion is doing with JS what should be done by CSS. Even if it wasn't the best answer, you should have upvoted it.